# Adding a ScrollView after adding TextFields/Unable to move the Keyboard with respect to Text Fields

Tags: swift

Can I add a scroll view after adding all the buttons and textFields in Xcode? Thanks! As when I do that I am not able to use any changes in view.

extension SecondViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    
    return true
    
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    
    if (textField == player2NameTextField || textField == player2CoinTextField ) {
        
         scrollView2.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 250), animated: true)
        
    }
    
}


func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    
    scrollView2.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), animated: true)
    
}
```

}

I am trying to auto adjust the keyboard on the screen with respect to the text field. But, it is not working. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: show your code.

Comment: @johnelemans I have shared my problem and the code above. Thanks!

Comment: look around for existing answers; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50832747/scrolling-a-scrollview-to-its-bottom-programmatically